# Modify the default location of & (by ref) in Visual Assist X's Extract Method macro

Tags: visual-assist-x

In Visual Assist X, the default way of extracting method is to put the & sign adjacent to the variable. Is there a way to change this behavior and make it put the & right after the class name instead? Currently using Visual Assist X,

```
int someInt = 1, anotherInt = 2;
someInt += 1; anotherInt += 1;
cout << someInt << anotherInt << endl;
```

Extracting the last two lines would result in a method signature like this:

```
void printInts(int &someInt, int &anotherInt)
```

I want the default signature to be:

```
void printInts(int& someInt, int& anotherInt)
```